# Add Slicer Selections to sheet in a list - Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table With a slicer that a user can make multiple selections in. I am trying to list the selected values in the slicer so they can then be joined together in another cell using CONCATENATE. I am using the code below.

At the moment, cells L5:L7 are populated with the first selection made in the slicer, but no others.

I did some research and found a possible solution with the CUBESET function, but I can't get it to work in my spreadsheet. Hence the VBA attempt. ANyone know whats wrong with it?

```
    Sub City_Click()

Dim cache As Excel.SlicerCache
Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_City")
Dim sItem As Excel.SlicerItem
For Each sItem In cache.SlicerItems

If sItem.Selected = True Then Range("L5").Value = sItem.Name
If sItem.Selected = True Then Range("L6").Value = sItem.Name
If sItem.Selected = True Then Range("L7").Value = sItem.Name

Next sItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a User Defined Function that you can call directly from the workbook that does this for you, and can be run on any type of Slicer, be it a 'traditional' PivotTable, an OLAP/PowerPivot PivotTable, or a Table Slicer. Just put this in a standard code module, and then in the workbook type the following:

=SlicerItems("Slicer_City")

```
Public Function SlicerItems(SlicerName As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = "|") As String

    Dim oSc As SlicerCache
    Dim oSi As SlicerItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lVisible As Long
    Dim sVisible() As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Volatile
    Set oSc = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName)
    If Not oSc Is Nothing Then
        With oSc
            If .FilterCleared Then
                SlicerItems = "(All)"
            Else
                If .OLAP Then
                    SlicerItems = Join(.VisibleSlicerItemsList, sDelimiter)
                    SlicerItems = Replace(SlicerItems, .SourceName, "")
                    SlicerItems = Replace(SlicerItems, ".&[", "")
                    SlicerItems = Replace(SlicerItems, "]", "")
                Else

                    lVisible = .VisibleSlicerItems.Count
                    If .VisibleSlicerItems.Count = 1 Then
                        SlicerItems = .VisibleSlicerItems(1).Name
                    Else
                        ReDim sVisible(1 To lVisible)
                        For i = 1 To lVisible
                            sVisible(i) = .VisibleSlicerItems(i).Name
                        Next i
                        SlicerItems = Join(sVisible, sDelimiter)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Else
        SlicerItems = SlicerName & " not found!"
    End If

End Function
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Cool. I forgot to say that there's an optional second argument that specifies the delimiter to use. The default is the pipe character | but you can specify others such as a comma.